# Does hibernate use transaction in cascading?

Tags: sql, hibernate

After googling for an hour, I haven't find an answer

Comment: yes, Hibernate does use transactions when performing cascading operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction is required for persist, save, remove... an object.

> You can't save or persist object without transaction you have to
> commit the transaction after saving the object otherwise it won't save
> in database. Without transaction you can only retrieve object from
> database.

> Cascading in Hibernate refers to the automatic persistence of related
> entities. When a change is made to an entity, such as an update or
> deletion, the changes can be cascaded to related entities as well.

So cascading operation does use a transaction that is used to persist, update, or remove the parent object.